# how to save changes on website with textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Im new at web developing.
I want something like:
A website, that everyone can enter. on the website u have 2 parts: one is filled with textbox so any user can write something in it and click button 'save comment'. He other side is filled with the execution of that button(it displays added text comment -but not just for a moment but that text is saved on that website). Simple as that... 
Do i use java script?
Ive been looking for the answers but kinda didnt know how to ask gooogle bout that
scheme on that website:

```
----------------------/----------------
-textbox--------------/--constant text-
--add comment button--/--wrote by user-
----------------------/----------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many possible ways to do that. One of the ways is to use html with jquery and send the result via web service (.asmx for instance) and save that result in a database (MSSQL for instance). So everytime you load the page you can get those saved results and display it on the relevant page. Another way is to use php with mysql or to use java...

If you don't want to use databases and server side code you can save the results in a cookie and then display those results in the page.

Comment: Thanks for directions